ECK Monitor Fleet Server Error When add TLS Certificate on Elasticsearch
When i add TLS Certificates in elasticsearch my fleet-server has error as detail below.
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2024-05-03T08:02:03.862Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"coordinator/coordinator.go","file.line":558},"message":"Unit state changed fleet-server-default (STARTING->FAILED): Error - failed version compatibility check with elasticsearch: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for *.thaibevapp.com, thaibevapp.com, not elasticsearch-es-http.default.svc","log":{"source":"elastic-agent"},"component":{"id":"fleet-server-default","state":"HEALTHY"},"unit":{"id":"fleet-server-default","type":"output","state":"FAILED","old_state":"STARTING"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-05-03T08:02:05.019Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"cmd/run.go","file.line":307},"message":"signal "terminated" received","log":{"source":"elastic-agent"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
This is my Fleet-Server and Elasticsearch yaml file.
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: default
spec:
  version: 8.11.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
        loadBalancerIP: 10.111.0.138 #don't forget to change
  config:
    #xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
    #xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
    #xpack.fleet.agents.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://elasticsearch-es-http.default.svc:9200"]
    xpack.fleet.agents.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://elasticapm.thaibevapp.com:9200"] #don't forget to change
    #xpack.fleet.agents.fleet_server.hosts: ["https://fleet-server-agent-http.default.svc:8220"]
    xpack.fleet.agents.fleet_server.hosts: ["https://10.111.0.140:8220"] #don't forget to change
    xpack.fleet.packages:
    - name: system
      version: latest
    - name: elastic_agent
      version: latest
    - name: fleet_server
      version: latest
    - name: kubernetes
      version: latest
    xpack.fleet.agentPolicies:
    - name: Fleet Server on ECK policy
      id: eck-fleet-server
      namespace: default
      monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
      unenroll_timeout: 900
      is_default_fleet_server: true
      package_policies:
      - name: fleet_server-1
        id: fleet_server-1
        package:
          name: fleet_server
    - name: Elastic Agent on ECK policy
      id: eck-agent
      namespace: default
      monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
      unenroll_timeout: 900
      is_default: true
      package_policies:
      - package:
          name: system
        name: system-1
      - package:
          name: kubernetes
        name: kubernetes-1
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: default
spec:
  version: 8.11.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 3
    config:
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
      xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data # Do not change this name unless you set up a volume mount for the data path.
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Gi #don't forget to change
        #storageClassName: hpe-standard
  http:
    tls:
      certificate:
        secretName: elastic-tls
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
        loadBalancerIP: 10.111.0.139 #don't forget to change
---
apiVersion: agent.k8s.elastic.co/v1alpha1
kind: Agent
metadata:
  name: fleet-server
spec:
  version: 8.11.0
  kibanaRef:
    name: kibana
  elasticsearchRefs:
  - name: elasticsearch
  mode: fleet
  fleetServerEnabled: true
  deployment:
    replicas: 1
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: fleet-server
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
        loadBalancerIP: 10.111.0.140 #don't forget to change
    tls:
      certificate:
        secretName: elastic-tls
---
apiVersion: agent.k8s.elastic.co/v1alpha1
kind: Agent
metadata: 
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: default
spec:
  version: 8.11.0
  kibanaRef:
    name: kibana
  fleetServerRef: 
    name: fleet-server
  mode: fleet
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: elastic-agent
        hostNetwork: true
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fleet-server
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
- apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - get
  - create
  - update
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fleet-server
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fleet-server
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fleet-server
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fleet-server
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
  - create
  - update
- nonResourceURLs:
  - "/metrics"
  verbs:
  - get
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elastic-agent
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io



